# Creating a timer to timeout and pop up an alert

Tags: iphone, nstimer

I'm trying to get a recent location using CLLocationManger.  If I cannot get one within 30 seconds, I want an alert to pop up saying that "we're having problems right now" or something along those lines.  In my CLLocationManager Delegate, I do this:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    NSDate *eventDate = newLocation.timestamp;
    NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
    NSTimer *timer;
    if (abs(howRecent) < 1.0) {     // process time if time is less than 1.0 seconds old.
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateCount:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];  
        return;
    }
```

My updateCount method:

```
- (void)updateCount:(NSTimer *)aTimer {
    count++;
    NSLog(@"%i", count);
    if (count == 30) {
        [aTimer invalidate];
        NSLog(@"Timer invalidated");
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Server Down" message:@"Sorry, but we cannot find your location at this time.  Please try again later." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}
```

But I don't see my alert get fired.  I tried with a repeating timer, but after it hits 30 seconds, and the alert is shown, it repeats again.  So I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here.  Thanks!

Comment: Side note: "Server Down" is not a good title for the message, as GPS does not use a server (although WiFi-based triangulation does).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just a small update to updateCount method :

```
- (void)updateCount:(NSTimer *)aTimer { 
    count++; 
    NSLog(@"%i", count); 
    if (count == 30) { 
        [aTimer invalidate]; 
        NSLog(@"Timer invalidated"); 
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Server Down" message:@"Sorry, but we cannot find your location at this time.  Please try again later." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil]; 
        [alert show]; 
        [alert release];
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
    } 
}
```

Don't use `NSTimer *timer;` in locationManager method. instead directly call timer = [[NSTimer....]] method and I think because there is one argument in updateCount method i.e. NSTimer and we are using different NSTimer instance so here is basically problem. Try without using argument in updateCount Method and invalidate the timer that is declared in .h file.

Comment: where does the variable timer come from?  Is this the assumption that I have an ivar of NSTimer *timer?  In my CLLocationManagerDelegate method, that is where I create the NSTimer.  Do I need to keep a reference to it as an ivar?

Comment: just declare NSTimer variable in .h file.. thats enough

Comment: Does not seem to work.  After the count reaches 30, I get the appropriate alert, but the count continues to increase and go on forever.  Any thoughts?  updateCount: continues to be called.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Comment: Have try to debug this?? did you get `Timer invalidated` in NSLog? Check whether if condition is called or not?? Also check that you use same timer instance that you are allocating in `LocationManager` method? Have you declare NSTimer in .h file??

Comment: I cannot remember if I got "Timer invalidated."  I will check next time this happens. (I'm not sure how to simulate this since I have it in GPS delegate when I'm having trouble connecting to GPS.  Is there a way to simulate no GPS or something similar to test this method?  I did get the UIAlert, so my assumption is I get the "Timer invalidated" message.  Yes I declared it in .h file.  How can I check for the same instance in the LocationManager method?  By the memory it points to?  Thanks again!

Comment: Isn't that the point of putting the timer in the delegate method though?  To see if the CLLocationManager continuously fails and therefore needs to show the user a message?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the documentation and found following paragraph in that.

> However, for a repeating timer, you must invalidate the timer object yourself by calling its invalidate method. Calling this method requests the removal of the timer from the current run loop; as a result, **you should always call the invalidate method from the same thread on which the timer was installed.**

So, for invalidating timer try calling performSelector.

I am not sure weather it will help or not but if it works then please post here so that other too can take advantage.